# Adding NSOperation from NSOperation

Tags: ios, multithreading, thread-safety, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Is it safe to add new `NSOperation` to `NSOperationQueue` from the `main()` method of `NSOperation`? Should I suspend `NSOperationQueue` before adding? Are there any gotchas in this? Do I have to add that in main thread using `dispatch_get_main_queue`?

Comment: You can make that an answer to accept, if you would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it should be safe until you are accessing the queue with one thread. You may also use mutex to lock the queue while adding operation into it.